# Is it possible to change access to Zenodo archive from closed to open?

Tags: publications, open-science, doi

I have a manuscript in review at a reputable journal. The code and data associated with this study will be made public on Github and releases archived in Zenodo with open access, providing a fixed DOI for the archive and one for each release.

At this stage, before the journal has formally accepted or rejected my manuscript, they are requiring me, as a matter of policy, to provide the final Zenodo DOI. This could mean I am expected to release the code (publicly, under an MIT license) before knowing whether the paper will actually be published. This might become a problem, so I'm looking into my options.

Is it possible to create a new **closed-access** archive on Zenodo, get a DOI for it, and then later change the access to **open-access** when I decide to do so, *without changing the original DOI in any way*? Of course I wouldn't be making any changes at all to the contents, only the access permissions.

That would neatly solve my problem, but I can't find any information confirming whether this is actually possible. Does anybody have direct experience relevant to that?

Comment: what do you mean by "final Zenodo DOI"? What if after the review process you need to make changes to your code or add additional data? Then the DOI would change.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible because Zenodo requires the underlying Github repository to be public.

Moreover, the journal likely requires you to provide the Zenodo DOI so that reviewers can access your data and code during the peer review process. If you do have concerns of your code being made public at this stage, you may contact the journal and outline your concerns. They may agree to allow you to directly submit the code to them in the first instance so that during the review phase, only peer reviewers and the journal editors have access. However, any such exception would be at the journals discretion.